# Javascript shuffle is not working as its supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, shuffle

This is the shuffle function I'm using:

```
function shuffle(o,l){
      for(var j, x, i = l; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
return o;
```

}

I'm using it within this code to shuffle a variable but somehow its shuffling both variables?

```
 function generate() {
    if (a = 1) {
    var shuffled = $.data;
     shuffle(shuffled,500);
    } else if (a = 2) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        console.log($.data[i]);
     }}
 }
```

It shuffles the 'shuffled' variable but somehow also shuffles $.data so its permanently shuffled regardless of which way the if goes.

Comment: `Array` is passed by reference, so you have to create a new array like use `o =o.slice()` to get one that won't affect `$.data`.

Comment: you mean like this ?

var shuffled =new Array(); 
shuffled = $.data;

If so then no that doesn't work either.

Comment: I figured out what you mean now and actually that did work. Thanks.

Comment: If you think, that did solve the question, you should accept the answer, so anyone that have the same question know the answer do solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, when you pass anything to a function that is not a primitive type (`string`, `number`, `boolean`,`null`, `undefined` and new `symbol` in ES6), it'll pass by reference, so when you altering the `o` in your `shuffle`, you're also changing the value on `$.data`.

To prevent this, you have to create a new `Array` from `$.data` and then alter the created one, so it'll affect the values in `$.data`.

In your function, you just need to change

```
for(var j, x, i = l; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
```

to

```
for(var j, x, i = l, o = o.slice(); i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
```

which we assign `o` to a new array created from input's `o`, then shuffle it and return.

As slice will return a new Array, the `o` is now different from `$.data`. Below is the test, you can run it and see what it logs.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10];

var len = 10;

// Origin, it return the same array that it accept.
function shuffle(o,l) {
      for(var j, x, i = l; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
      return o;
}


// Altered, it'll return a new array.
function shuffleAlt(o,l) {
      for(var j, x, i = l, o = o.slice(); i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
      return o;
}

var c = shuffle(a, len);
console.log(a);
console.log(c);
console.log("c === a :" , c === a);
var d = shuffleAlt(b, len);
console.log(b);
console.log(d);
console.log("d === b :" , d=== b)
```